# Cronjob -e task not running but works without cron

Tags: database, cron, backup

I am trying to make a backup of my database in debian and put it on a specific folder once a day

I use this:

> mysqldump -u mysqlacc -pMYPASSWORD mytable --single-transaction
>   --quick --lock-tables=false > /var/www/html/backup/mytable-backup-$(date "+%b_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S").sql'

and it works well, the file is put in the respective folder, but once i put this line in crontab -e, it won't run it:

> 0 17 * * * mysqldump -u mysqlacc -pMYPASSWORD mytable
>   --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false > /var/www/html/backup/mytable-backup-$(date "+%b_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S").sql

Any idea what seems to be wrong?

Comment: is the absoulte path of the dump folder correct? check the error log of the server it may can helps

Comment: Yes, it's correct, it has to be as the file gets there without the cron.

I checked cron logs, but it doesn't show any errors.

Comment: is there a time difference between your clock time and the remote server time?

Comment: There is but i am aware of that, i put the server time. I used another command line (with ssh) which ran well with cron.

Comment: try to add --host=IP_ADDRESS_OF_DB_SERVER, there is no DB_name in your commandline, only mytable which should be the DB_NAME instead